# Is there a way to pass compile time constant to repr directive?

Tags: rust

```
const CELL_ALIGNMENT: usize = std::mem::align_of::<EntryType>();
#[repr(align(CELL_ALIGNMENT))]
pub struct AlignedCell;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct AlignedHeader {
    _align: [AlignedCell; 0],
    count: usize,
}
```

CELL_ALIGNMENT is a constant. But it looks like `repr` doesn't allow constant. Only literal is allowed. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I think it can only be done using procedural macro.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use an expression in `#[repr(align(_))]`. It must be a literal.

The next best thing: you can assert the alignment of your struct matches another at compile-time by using the [static-assertions](https://crates.io/crates/static_assertions) crate:

```
#[repr(align(8))]
pub struct AlignedCell;

static_assertions::assert_eq_align!(AlignedCell, EntryType);
```

It doesn't set the alignment automatically, but you'll get a compiler error if its wrong.

Comment: The `static-assertions` crate is no longer needed. You can use a simple `const _: () = assert!(std::mem::align_of::<AlignedCell>() == std::mem::align_of::<EntryType>());`